# When we speak of ordinal, do we always refer to natural numbers and theirs successors?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I'm studying set theory using Halmos'book.

In the book, the definition of an ordinal is :

> A set $S$ is an ordinal if and only if $S$ is strictly well-ordered with respect to set membership and every element of $S$ is also a subset of $S$.

Does the above definition imply that a set $x$ which are not $w$ (the set of all natural numbers) and its successors ($w^+$, $(w^+)^+$,...) must be a natural number ?

(i.e. does there exist, say an ordinal $cat$ or $orange$ of which every element of it is one of its subsets ? or when we speak of ordinals, it must be 0, 1, 2, ..., $w$, $w^+$, $(w^+)^+$, ... i.e. the natural numbers and its successors)

Thank you very much for your explanation!

Comment: I don't see how that definition should imply anything about what is or isn't a natural number.

Comment: I suspect when you are thinking about *cat* and *orange* you might have the intuitive idea of [urelements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement). A urelement cannot be an ordinal, since your definition requires them to be sets. Ordinals cannot contain *urelements*, since otherwise these must be subsets and thus sets. The other thing can can mess up that definition of ordinal are [Quine atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement#Quine_atoms). I don't have Halmos' book here, but likely there are no urelements nor Quine atoms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are many more ordinals -- you've only seen the tip of the iceberg! The first ordinal not on your list is usually called $\omega \cdot 2$ (read "omega times two"), and it consists exactly of the natural numbers, the set $\omega$, and all of $\omega$'s iterated successors. That is,
$$
\omega \cdot 2 = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, \omega, \omega^+, (\omega^+)^+, \ldots\}.
$$
(Usually what you call $\omega^+$ is called $\omega + 1$, and $(\omega^+)^+ = \omega + 2$, and so on.) You could call $\omega \cdot 2$ *cat* if you want to, but $\omega \cdot 2$ is definitely a more common name for it. :-)

Presumably you can now guess at what $\omega \cdot 3$ is, and $\omega \cdot 4$, up to $\omega \cdot n$ for any natural $n$. But we're not done of course, after that you can add up all of those (and their successors) and get $\omega \cdot \omega$, or $\omega^2$. And then you might be able to guess what $\omega^2 \cdot 2$ is, and $\omega^2 \cdot 3$, and maybe $\omega^2 \cdot \omega$ -- and then the notation $\omega^3$ starts to make sense. And then $\omega^4$, and then eventually $\omega^\omega$. And still this is only a very small tip of the iceberg!

Enjoy exploring!

Edit: based on the clarification in the comments, maybe this better answers your question.

**Proposition:** For any ordinals $\alpha, \beta$, either $\alpha \subseteq \beta$ or $\beta \subseteq \alpha$.

**Proof:** Suppose towards a contradiction that this is false; that is, $\alpha$ contains elements not in $\beta$, and vice versa. Since $\alpha$ is a well-order, we can find the least element of $\alpha$ that is not in $\beta$; call it $\alpha'$. Similarly, let $\beta'$ be the least element in $\beta$ that is not in $\alpha$.

Let us show that $\alpha' = \beta'$, contradicting our assumption. It suffices to prove $\alpha' \subseteq \beta'$ and $\beta' \subseteq \alpha'$ -- WLOG let's prove the former.

Take $\alpha'' \in \alpha'$. This means that $\alpha'' \in \alpha$, and in the ordering in $\alpha$, $\alpha'' < \alpha'$, so by definition of $\alpha'$ we have that $\alpha'' \in \beta$. We cannot have that $\beta' < \alpha''$, because that would mean $\beta' \in \alpha''$ and thus $\beta' \in \alpha$. Similarly, we cannot have $\beta' = \alpha''$, because then we would also have $\beta' \in \alpha$. Thus we have $\alpha'' < \beta'$, or in other words $\alpha'' \in \beta'$. It follows that $\alpha' \subseteq \beta'$.

This is a contradiction, so $\alpha \subseteq \beta$ or $\beta \subseteq \alpha$. $\square$

That tells you, basically, that all the ordinals there are, are in one long line. Every ordinal (as a set) consists exactly of all ordinals below it, and there is no "branching". In particular, the natural numbers are the only finite ordinals, and every infinite ordinal contains the natural numbers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, actually i understand that there are many of ordinal numbers as you stated (i.e. up to $w^w$). What I am not 100% sure here (which leads to my question) is that when we speak of ordinals, does there exist any $cat$ number which is ordinal but it is not a natural number, not $w$, not $w2$,... (in general not something related to natural number), like something defined "in parallel" and outside of anything relate to natural numbers, and it happens to be an ordinal. Could you please have a look at my question one more time ? Thanks!!!!

Comment: Ah, so, @InTheSearchForKnowledge, you are asking whether there could be anything _other_than_ the "minimal required" collection of ordinals?

Comment: @paulgarrett: Hi, yes, I think so. In fact the point is that in the definition of ordinal, there is no word saying that an ordinal relares to natural numbers (in some sense) and it seems to imply the natural numbers (and theirs successors, etc). It is because for a natural number (or their successor, etc), each initial segment of each of its subsets belong to the set. I'm asking myself if there exist something which has the same property but have nothing to do with natural number. We are studying "set" theory and it is much general (we are talking about objects) than just natural numbers.

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge, I have updated my answer, hopefully it is more helpful this way.

Comment: @MeesdeVries: Hi, thanks very much for your edit, i marked your answer satisfactory, but could you please explain me why intuitively that there couldn't exist any ordinal number other than natural numbers and "their successors" ? I think it is because the common root is 0 and as the natural numbers are defined recursively, it makes the ordinal numbers queue in 1 line, do you think so ?

Comment: @MeesdeVries: Hi, do you have any freetime to look at my question above ? It would be very appreciated as I am a little bit stuck.. many thanks!!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge I do not understand the question in your second-to-last comment, but let me try to say something that might be useful to you: it is not especially practical to think about ordinals in isolation. The raison d'être for ordinals is that they are a canonical representation of _well-orders_. So the question of why all ordinals are in a line is really: why are all well-orders isomorphic to initial segments of each other? The above is essentially a proof of that fact.

Comment: (In general trying to ask too many follow-up questions in comments is not usually a good idea; formulate a good, mathematical question and then ask it in a new question, possibly linking this one for context.)